# Getting Twitter timeline, including Retweets, using JSON

Tags: api, twitter

How can I get my Twitter timeline, including Retweets, using JSON?

This URL does not show Retweets.

```
http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/S11cc.json?include_trs=true&callback=twitterCallback2&count=7
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a typo in the url. It should be `include_rts` and not `include_trs`.

Comment: Documentation here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/home_timeline#api-param-include_rts. I found this question before I found the documentation, so thanks @vsr.